# Research studies on electronic vs paper record keeping accuracy

Tags: database-design

Does anyone know of any research studies to test whether electronic or paper record keeping is more **accurate** than the other?  Obviously electronic record keeping is more efficient, but efficient doesn't necessarily mean better accuracy in recording information.

I have a client that is holding on dearly to their old paper system because of data accuracy conceptions.  I'd love to be able to point to a research study that addresses which way of doing things is more accurate.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good site for this, but I'm curious as to HOW the client thinks that paper is more accurate than electronic - both systems are only as accurate as the garbage or data put into them

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good site for this either. Won't be offended if this gets bumped!  I think what they're thinking is that when you write something down on paper you're not subject to stray mouse clicks and the like.  What you write down is what you write down.  And I know that so much has to do with the systems in place.  But I can just imagine some research study where a bunch of volunteers were asked to digitally record a series of data points.  Then another group of volunteers asked to record on paper the same data.  And then you could see which was more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just finished reading the National Transportation Library report on EVALUATION OF EMERGING TECHNOLOGIES FOR TRAFFIC CRASH REPORTING [STUDY OF DATA ACCURACY](http://ntl.bts.gov/DOCS/97023/ch03/body_ch03_01.html) and they have some pretty meaningful insights.

1. analysis found a mean of 3.24 errors per paper accident report and 1.10 per computerized report.
2. Missing data occurred over 6 times more often on the paper based reports.
3. Data was entered inaccurately more than twice as often on the paper based reports.
4. Unintelligible entries were found on the paper reports more than 10 times more frequently.